# NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've install `devise gem`
by adding it to gemfile and typing bundle 
Then I type

```
rails generate devise admin
```

I can't have devise named users cause I already have users.
So  get an error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `devise' for Admin (call 'Admin.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/home/direwolf/rails_projects/unicom/app/models/admin.rb:4:in `<class:Admin>'
/home/direwolf/rails_projects/unicom/app/models/admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/direwolf/rails_projects/unicom/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/direwolf/rails_projects/unicom/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to run the generator command:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

This will load all of Devises configuration options.

Comment: thnx bro)))))))))))))))))))))))